# Paypal payment response without IPN listener?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm adding very simple membership renewal functionality to a web site using PayPal Payments Standard buttons.  We only have 300 or so members, so a simple e-comm solution like this should work fine.

I'd like to capture some sort of confirmation that I can then capture on my end so that I can insert it into the database.  I've seen the IPN listener method, but it seems more complex than I really need - all I really need is to pass the confirmation code via a URL variable in the return URL, i.e. http://www.example.com/landing?transactionid=abc123.  Is this possible?  Also, is there a way to pass my own dynamic variable (for instance, a membership ID) into the form and have that be a part of the return string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use express checkout which is a two step process requiring pre-authorization and then charging a customer. If you are accepting echecks you will eventually need to use IPN to update the original transaction. You can pass a dynamic variable using the `custom` field in Paypal.

Either way one of the two methods is required to process a transaction securely - what is stopping someone from typing the URL you are suggesting?